# How to use a for loop on an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, for-loop

I need to use a `for` loop to take the last four strings off the `more_stuff` array.

Here is my code:

```
# assigns string Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar to variable 
ten_things
ten_things = "Apples Oranges Crows Telephone Light Sugar"

# prints Wait there are not ten things on that list. Let's fix that.
puts "Wait there are not 10 things in that list. Let's fix that."

# first seperates string ten_things into an array at space character, then 
# assigns the new array to variable stuff
stuff = ten_things.split(' ')
# assigns array to more stuff with strings, Day, Night, Song, Frisbee, Girl, 
# and Boy
more_stuff = ["Day", "Night", "Song", "Frisbee", "Corn", "Banana", "Girl", 
"Boy"]

# using math to make sure there's 10 items

# assigns fifth through eighth elements in array more_stuff to array stuff_3
stuff_3 = more_stuff[4..8]
# prints array stuff_3 in brackets
puts "#{stuff_3}"
# for all strings in stuff_3
stuff_3.each do |stuff_3|
  # pops the last item off of stuff_3
  next_one = stuff_3.pop
  # puts adding (next_one)
  puts "Adding #{next_one}"
  # adds (next_one) to array stuff
  stuff.push(next_one)
# ends for loop
end
```

Also here is the error that comes up when I run it from Powershell:

```
Wait there are not 10 things in that list. Let's fix that.
["Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"]
ex38for.rb:17:in `block in <main>': undefined method `pop' for "Corn":String 
(NoMethodError)
    from ex38for.rb:16:in `each'
    from ex38for.rb:16:in `<main>'
```

I'm confused how `for` loops work, specifically `each` and where to put stuff in the array command.

Answer (score 3):

What `pop` does is to take the last element or value on an array (when is used without specifying the number of elements):

```
p stuff_3.pop
# => "Boy"
p stuff_3.pop(2)
# => ["Banana", "Girl"]
```

But in your case you're trying to use `pop` with an element that's inside the main array.

If you check it doing it outside your `each` method:

```
puts stuff_3.pop
# => Boy
```

Then that will print `Boy` because is the last element within the `stuff_3` array which you declare as `more_stuff[4..8]`:

```
stuff_3 = more_stuff[4..8]
p stuff_3
# => ["Corn", "Banana", "Girl", "Boy"]
```

But then, when you do `stuff_3.each do |stuff_3|` you're using the same name `stuff_3` to access each element inside that array, which has the same name. So there's where you're getting the `undefined method 'pop' for "Corn":String` error, because `pop` is waiting for an `array` and if you iterate over each element inside `stuff_3` you're getting `String` elements.

A possible solution is that you use a different name to access the elements when you use `each` with the `stuff_3` array, maybe just as `stuffs`, and that will give you "Adding Boy" and "Adding Girl".

Or maybe any word to refer the elements inside `stuff_3` being different to this one could work, because you're not accessing those elements, you also could use `_` to specify they're not being used:

```
stuff_3.each do |_|
  next_one = stuff_3.pop
  puts "Adding #{next_one}"
  stuff.push(next_one)
end
```

This would be `stuff` before pushing the elements:

```
["Apples", "Oranges", "Crows", "Telephone", "Light", "Sugar"]
```

And after:

```
["Apples", "Oranges", "Crows", "Telephone", "Light", "Sugar", "Boy", "Girl"]
```

Comment: Of course there are a lot of things to add as suggestions, but could be better to use a discussion chat, or maybe to specify what you're trying to do and what do you want to get to focus the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You are shadowing the outer variable:

```
stuff_3.each do |stuff_3|
  stuff_3.pop
```

Within this block of code, the "inner" `stuff_3` variable takes precedence over the "outer" `stuff_3` variable.

That's why you are seeing an error message:

> undefined method `pop' **for "Corn":String**

Shadowing outer variables like this is generally considered bad practice, as it leads to confusing code and "unexpected" behaviour (like what you found here!). A simple fix is to just use a different variable name:

```
stuff_3.each do |stuff_3_item|
  stuff_3.pop
```

...Although I think what you're actually trying to do here should be written a little differently - e.g.

```
stuff_3.each do |stuff_3_item|
  puts "Adding #{stuff_3_item}"
  stuff.push(stuff_3_item)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's focus on this part of your code:

```
stuff_3.each do |stuff_3|
  # pops the last item off of stuff_3
  next_one = stuff_3.pop
  # puts adding (next_one)
  puts "Adding #{next_one}"
  # adds (next_one) to array stuff
  stuff.push(next_one)
# ends for loop
end
```

This code: `stuff_3.each do |stuff_3|` is a loop which takes each item in `stuff_3`, saves it to a local variable (which you have also called `stuff_3`) and executes the following code with it.

So when you call `stuff_3.pop`, you're actually calling `pop` on the local variable which contains only one item, instead of the array containing all the items. Because of this, you get the error:

> undefined method `pop' for "Corn":String

Which is telling you that you're calling `pop` on a single item (the String "Corn" in this case), instead of an array of items like you expected.

One way to fix this is to change your code like so:

```
stuff_3.each do |next_one|
  # puts adding (next_one)
  puts "Adding #{ next_one }"
  # adds (next_one) to array of stuff
  stuff.push(next_one)
# ends for loop
end
```

This code will go through each item in `stuff_3` and add it to `stuff`. But it may work differently than you expect:

- `stuff_3.each` will iterate through items from first to last, whereas `pop` takes the last item first, meaning that this code will add items to your array in opposite order.
- `stuff_3.each` goes through items without removing them, whereas `pop` will remove each item, eventually leaving your `stuff_3` array empty.

If you don't want these variations, you can still use `pop` like so:

```
stuff_3.times do |i|
  #pops the last item off of stuff_3
  next_one = stuff_3.pop
  # puts adding (next_one)
  puts "Adding #{next_one}"
  # adds (next_one) to array of stuff
  stuff.push(next_one)
# ends for loop
end
```

This code uses `stuff_3.times` to execute a loop as many times as there are items in stuff_3. So if stuff_3 has 3 items in it, the loop executes 3 times. The variable `i` is a counter that starts at 0 and counts up each time the loop is executed. In this case, `times` works much more like the traditional for-loop and the above code will execute pretty much exactly like you expected yours to execute.